# Python constructor recursion confusion

Tags: python

I'm trying to trace someone's code and I've encountered a section that I'm a little confused about. Firstly the file from the github repo I'm looking at is https://github.com/tahoe-lafs/zfec/blob/master/zfec/easyfec.py. But I'll paste the part that I'm confused about below. I have 2 questions. Firstly,

From `easyfec.py`

```
import zfec

class Decoder(object):
    def __init__(self, k, m):
        self.fec = zfec.Decoder(k, m)

    def decode(self, blocks, sharenums, padlen):
        """
        @param padlen: the number of bytes of padding to strip off;  Note that
            the padlen is always equal to (blocksize times k) minus the length
            of data.  (Therefore, padlen can be 0.)
        """
        data = b''.join(self.fec.decode(blocks, sharenums))
        if padlen:
            return data[:-padlen]
        else:
            return data
```

Looking at the constructor of the class where it has `self.fec = zfec.Decoder(k, m)`, `zfec` is imported, but `zfec` is the directory that this file resides in. I therefore looked at the `__init__.py` file in `zfec` directory. Which is shown below:

From `__init__.py`:

```
from ._version import get_versions
__version__ = get_versions()['version']
del get_versions

from ._fec import Encoder, Decoder, Error
from . import easyfec, filefec, cmdline_zfec, cmdline_zunfec

quiet_pyflakes=[__version__, Error, Encoder, Decoder, cmdline_zunfec, filefec, cmdline_zfec, easyfec]
```

This is where I'm confused, it seems like the `Decoder` from this file is imported from `easyfec.py` (or maybe I'm wrong), but doesn't this result in an infinite loop of calling the `Decoder` constructor?

My second question is from `easyfec.py`, in the `decode` method. The first line in that method is `data = b''.join(self.fec.decode(blocks, sharenums))`. How is it able to call itself if it only has two parameters but the method takes 3 arguments? I'm guessing it's because it's calling a different method? But if that is the case I can't seem to find it.

Your guidance is appreciated.

Comment: The `Decoder` that is being used by the `Decoder` you showed was imported from the module `_fec` - there's no recursion here.  I'd guess that `_fec.Decoder` is something working at a lower level, perhaps it's actually a C module.

Comment: Thanks Jason, but how come I'm not able to find a ```Decoder``` reference in the ```fec.c``` file?

Comment: The source code to the `_fec` module turns out to be `_fecmodule.c`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking closely at **init**.py, Encoder and Decoder appear to be imported from a _fec module that you have to build yourself with the provided setup script.

The following line:

```
from . import easyfec, filefec, cmdline_zfec, cmdline_zunfec
```

Is only importing easyfec, filefec, etc into the zfec module's namespace, so you would still have to do:

```
from zfec import easyfec
easyfec.Decoder(...)
```

easyfec is a python interface to the corresponding C API, hence the parameter differences.

Comment: Ok thanks, but if ```Encoder``` and ```Decoder``` are imported form the ```_fec``` module, I should be able to see ```Encoder``` and ```Decoder``` in the ```fec.c``` file?

Comment: Most of the definitions are contained in _fecmodule.c